# How to shuffle a selected column with repeating values in python without assigning the same value as original dataframe

Tags: python

I want to shuffle the column "chr" in my dataframe keeping the rest of the values intact. I want to make sure that the new values are not same as the one in original dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> abuniq = pd.read_csv("/home/m203319/nonenh/abuniq.csv")
>>> abuniq
     chr  enhmid strand  tss  dist
0   chr1      60    pos  791   731
1   chr1     993    pos  919    74
2   chr2      72    neg  388   316
3   chr2      92    neg  388   296
4   chr2     172    neg  388   216
5   chr2     484    neg  388    96
6   chr3     100    neg  231   131
7   chr3     362    neg  231   131
8   chr4     163    pos  310   147
9   chr4     464    pos  612   148
10  chr4     756    pos  774    18
11  chr5     290    neg  339    49
12  chr5     538    pos  487    51
13  chr5     730    pos  487   243
>>> #Create df with only chr and drop rest
...
>>> ab_drop = abuniq.drop(['enhmid','strand', 'tss', 'dist'], axis=1)
>>> ab_drop
     chr
0   chr1
1   chr1
2   chr2
3   chr2
4   chr2
5   chr2
6   chr3
7   chr3
8   chr4
9   chr4
10  chr4
11  chr5
12  chr5
13  chr5
>>> # Shuffle the chr column
...
>>> ab_shuffle1 = ab_drop.sample(frac=1, random_state=1)
>>> ab_shuffle1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
>>> ab_shuffle1
     chr
0   chr2
1   chr3
2   chr3
3   chr2
4   chr4
5   chr2
6   chr1
7   chr5
8   chr1
9   chr5
10  chr4
11  chr4
12  chr5
13  chr2
>>>
```

After shuffling some of the values has not changed i.e. for index 3, 5 and 12. What would be the best way to do shuffling without the same value being assigned.

Comment: This could be very difficult because of all the duplicate values in that column.

Comment: Do they have to be shuffled randomly, or you just need to reassign them in some way that they don't have the same values as the original?

Comment: Are the duplicate values always in adjacent rows in the original?

Comment: If that's true, find the length of the longest run. Then just shift all the values by that number of rows.

Comment: Does the resulting order need to be actually random?, or would it be enough for every slot to be different than previous and the set of values to be the same?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I just need to reassign them randomly so that they don't have the same values as the original. The chr column will always be sorted, so duplicates will always be in adjacent rows. But I do not want to assign all of them to a same vale after shuffling.

Comment: I think this is a very difficult constraint-solving problem, you may need to look for a dynamic programming library.

Comment: In some cases there might not even be a possible shuffling.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for the reply. Would it be possible to create a list of all the values in Chr (not distinct) and then loop through each record and randomly pick  from list without replacement with condition that previous value is not picked. I am new to python, so not sure if this would be feasible or fast enough since my original dataset has more than 1000 rows.

Comment: That's how you would have to do it, but what happens if you get to the end and there are no available slots that weren't in the original table?

Comment: You'd need to go back and undo some of the assignments. This could take forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is quick, dirty, and as Barmar pointed out could lead to no solution, but it would work in the simplest cases with little burden.

```
while True:
    new = np.random.permutation(abuniq[‘chr’])
    if abuniq[abuniq[‘chr’] == new].empty:
        break
abuniq[‘chr’] = new
```